# Cakephp Get key & value from database

Tags: php, database, cakephp

I just Created Web-installer in Cakephp and now i stated working on writing and reading configuration on database table .. but dont know how to start. do i have to create a model.. seems thats not the right way could some one show me the way.

**UPDATE: just need to know reading config based from database table**

[Web Insaller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zG8LP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout how the popular CakePHP CMS [Croogo](http://croogo.org/) does it.